# iOS: Setting primary language for app when localizing

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I have built an app for swedish language only. Now I have added multilanguage support (english uk/us, german, spanish) and would like to submit the app to all App Stores in the world.

The problem is that I have chosen swedish as the primary language in Itunes Connect when creating my account.

Reading several threads about this I have come to the conclusion that if I submit the app now, the default language will be swedish for languages I haven't localized. This is a huge problem since there seems to be no way of changing this primary language.

Anyone know what can be done?

On the upside: When using a link in Itunes Connect "Version summary" I can see the language is in english when for example choosing "Slovenia" or any other country that hasn't been localized... Can I trust this really? Not according to several forum threads, example:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1678830?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1657193?start=0&tstart=0

Thanks

Comment: Is this question about the App Store or the app?

Comment: @DavidDunham It's about Itunes Connect actually I guess. Do you think Stackoverflow is the wrong forum for this? Apple dev forum gave nothing =/

Comment: I would trust it for now, then submit a bug with Apple or contact the iTunes folks if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now released the app and tried out several different App Stores and it seems like it does take english as the default langauge, not swedish which I have as primary.

This goes against what has been said before in forums and such. Also, Apple called me and we talked about this, but the support person wasn't sure why it worked either :)

For future people coming here, here is how it works for me now:

-I have localized in Itunes Connect for german, spanish and english.
In these App Stores the language will be displayed correctly for each country.

-I have NOT localized for Canada. If I add the app to this app store the language will be in swedish (your primary language).

-A language that is not possible to localize, like estonian, will in fact display my english app description in the Estonian app store. This could have something to do with the "Localization native development region" as Digital Robot stated as a comment.

Comment: In some / many cases the actual language shown is because of the lang preferences of the user. Any user can set this in OS X settings, or other operating systems and/or browsers. I think only as a last resort Localization native development is used. Still I'm not 100% sure about this. :-P I'm getting the feeling Apple isn't either.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this key on the Info.plist? To force iTC to see english as the default language. [image]